# Expressjs request body empty on heroku (using domain mapping)

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, cross-domain

So I have a form which is posting it's data to my '/message' endpoint. Everything is working fine when testing locally and also on heroku using the designated subdomain (myapp.heroku.com).

Since I don't want to use myapp.heroku.com, I registered a Domain (different host, not heroku) which is pointing to the heroku subdomain. Testing the form on mydomain.com, gives me an empty req.body in my express backend. Do I need to set up CORS headers in express for this to work? Everything else is working fine and the post is happening, it's just that the req.body turns up empty. Content type is also set properly (application/json).

Did you guys run into this problem? What did you do about it?

Backbone view helper where the Request is made. I logged the serializeObject output and everything is fine (data is correct, loggs only once).

```
    handleFormSubmit: function (e) {

        var $btn;

        e.preventDefault();

        if (!this.model) {

            // get data and create model
            this.model = new app.Models.Message($(e.target).serializeObject());

            // setup error/success handlers
            this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', function(a,b,c) {
                TweenLite.to('.msgSuccess', 0.3, {opacity: 1, ease:Quad.easeInOut});
                $btn.button('reset');
                $btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            });
            this.listenTo(this.model, 'error', function(a,b,c) {
                console.log(a, b, c);
                $btn.button('reset');
            });

            // save, initiates the request
            this.model.save();
        }

    }
```

Just to be sure, this is the backbone message model. Nothing fancy:

```
app.Models.Message = Backbone.Model.extend({

    url: '/message',

});
```

This is the '/message' view in the backend. As pointed out in the comments, I'm using Keystone as a CMS. I removed all the mail sending logic to keep things as simple as possible:

```
exports = module.exports = function(req, res) {
    console.log('attempting to send mail..');
    console.log(req.body);
};
```

I don't think these snippets are going to help much since this is not exactly rocket science and the problem clearly is not in the code but has something to do with heroku/the domain mapping.

Comment: Hm.. That's weird. CORS should not affect the body afaik. You could try adding `req.on("data", function(chunk){console.log(chunk.toString())})` listener to see if something is coming through. This listener won't be affected by express thus removing anything related to express itself.

Comment: I tried that, but I'm not sure where to put it. I'm using Keystone and putting it into the message view did nothing. But it might as well be too late for the event to trigger properly. Afaik I can't change anything inside node_modules, since it is not added into git (and that is where I think the request is managed in the first place).

Comment: Another thing i just noticed is, if i use myapp.com the request seems to hit twice, both times with an empty body. Using myapp.heroku.com it only hits once and works perfectly.. what the hell?!?

Comment: This could be surely from application end. can you please drop code snippet.

Comment: I added code snippets to my original question.